# Issue filling a 2d array of chars in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I was writing a program that involves a two dimensional array of values, and I was planning on printing them to terminal with ANSI escape codes. To test my code to for printing values with ANSI escape codes, I filled the array with a gradient. However, when I tried this, only the top row had the gradient. I have no idea what I am doing wrong here. I have tried using `int`s instead of `char`s, but nothing I tried has worked.

My code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>


char grid[64][64];

void printGrid(void) {
    for (char i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        for (char j = 0; j < 64; j++) {
            char currentCell = grid[(int)i][(int)j];
            std::cout << '\033' << "[48;2;" << std::to_string(currentCell) << ';' << std::to_string(currentCell) << ';' << std::to_string(currentCell) << "m  ";
        }
        std::cout << '\033' << "[0m" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    for (char i; i < 64; i++) {
        for (char j; j < 64; j++) {
            grid[(int)i][(int)j] = ((j+1)*2)-1;
        }
    }
    
    printGrid();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Characters with low encoding values tend to be unprintable. `std::to_string(currentCell)` should produce a string holding a number. I recommend adding to the question a brief example of the output you are getting and the output you are expecting.

Comment: *To test my code to for printing values with ANSI escape codes,* -- Shouldn't you first try a much simpler program, to confirm that ANSI escape codes are actually working?  Maybe like a simple "Hello World" with ANSI escape sequences?  Why complicate this by introducing a two-dimensional array?

Comment: `for (char i; i < 64; i++)` forgot to set initial value to 0, the same for J loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was hiding in plain sight. I forgot to initialize my iterators to 0 in some of my for loops.

> `for (char i; i < 64; i++)` forgot to set initial value to 0, the same for J loop –
> Iłya Bursov